# "einschließlich" + Personalpronomen = welcher Fall?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, personal-pronoun

Ich möchte den folgenden Satzteil

> Viele von uns, auch ich, sind ...

unter Verwendung von "einschließlich" umformulieren:

> Viele von uns, einschließlich ___ selbst, sind ...

Nun ist "einschließlich" laut [Duden eine Genitivpräposition](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einschlieszlich_inklusive_samt_nebst), die aber Ausnahmen, wie z.B. vor Substantiven ohne Artikel oder vor Namen, zulässt. Wie ist ein Personalpronomen in diesem Zusammenhang zu werten und was ist somit die richtige Formulierung des obigen Satzteils?

> Viele von uns, einschließlich ich selbst, sind ...
>
> Viele von uns, einschließlich meiner selbst, sind ...
>
> Viele von uns, einschließlich mir selbst, sind ...

Comment: *Viele von uns, einschließlich meiner Wenigkeit, sind …*

Comment: @Janka Das könnte Genitiv oder Dativ sein.

Answer (score 3):

Hier ist eine der Stellen, an denen "richtig" und "gebräuchlich" in der deutschen Sprache besonders stark auseinenderklaffen.

*einschließlich* ist (genauso wie *ausschließlich*), wie du richtig schreibst, eine Präposition, die den Genitiv verlangt. Der Genitiv von "ich" wird allerdings kaum benutzt und ist, auch selbst unter Muttersprachlern, kaum bekannt - er lautet *meiner*.

Vollkommen richtig (aber auch relativ ungebräuchlich) wäre

> Viele von uns, einschließlich meiner selbst, sind ...

Wesentlich gebräuchlicher ist hier die Verwendung des Dativs

> Viele von uns, einschließlich mir selbst, sind ...

oder des Nominativs

> Viele von uns, einschließlich ich selbst, sind ...

Die an sich beide grammatikalisch falsch (zum Nominativ: s.u.) sind, aber sich bei weitem nicht so "gehoben" anhören wie der Genitiv.

Für den Nominativ könnte man ein "grammatikalisches Schlupfloch" finden, denn die meisten Grammatiken erlauben es, bei Genitiv-Präpositionen im Singular stattdessen den Nominativ zu verwenden, wenn kein Artikel steht:

> Sie haben ihm alles, einschließlich Geld, weggenommen

statt

> Sie haben ihm alles, einschließlich des Geldes, weggenommen.

Meinem Sprachgefühl nach würde ich - in geschriebener Sprache - den Nominativ den anderen Formen vorziehen - Der eigentlich richtige Genitiv hört sich schon ziemlich "geschraubt" an. Im normalen Gespräch verwende ich hier trotz besseren Wissens den Dativ.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Deine Antwort. Ich hatte mich speziell auf die Ausnahmeregelung "einschließlich" + Name bezogen. Ein Personalpronomen erfüllt ja dieselbe Aufgabe wie ein Name, nämlich die Herstellung einer eindeutigen Referenz einer Person. In dem Beispiel ist "selbst" als Betonung der Rolle des Sprechers verwendet und könnte daher auch weggelassen werden. Der Satz würde dann lauten "Viele von uns, einschließlich meiner / ich / mir, sind ...". Ist die Verwendung von "meiner" an dieser Stelle tatsächlich grammatikalisch korrekt? Die Verwendung von "meiner selbst" klingt dagegen geläufiger.

Comment: *meiner* ist absolut korrekt, auch ohne "selbst" - nur eben nicht "geläufig". Das Sprachgefühl scheint irgendwas zu vermissen, auf das sich der Genitiv beziehen könnte - Das fehlt aber gar nicht.

Comment: Dem gegenüber steht allerdings die Ausnahmeregelung für Namen (z.B. "Viele von uns, einschließlich Brigitte, sind ..."); hier steht der Name im Nominativ. Da Personalpronomen bzgl. der grammatikalischen Struktur eines Satzes dieselbe Aufgabe wie Namen erfüllen, würde ich hier ein Ausbleiben der Flexion erwarten (d.h. dass nicht umgangssprachlich der Dativ, sondern ganz regulär der Nominativ Verwendung finden würde). Oder beziehen sich solche Ausnahmeregelungen immer nur auf eine bestimmte Wortart und nicht allgemein auf Gruppen, die dieselbe grammatikalische Funktion erfüllen?

Comment: @a_guest  Dein Statement „Personalpronomen erfüllen dieselbe Aufgabe wie Namen“ musst du belegen. Das halte ich für unzutreffend. Personalpronomen erfüllen auch dieselbe Aufgabe wie ganz normale Substantive.